# How to load an index.html file with Webpack 3, Typescript and file-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-3

I try to load my `index.html` file via the `file-loader` and Webpack 3.

My `webpack.config.ts`looks like this:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: "./src/app.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".html"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
            }, {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};

export default config;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't load my `src/index.html` file to the `dist` folder. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the index file from the `src` folder to the `dist` folder?

Comment: Did you import that index.html somewhere in your modules? Webpack will only load files that is imported somewhere in the file-tree beneath the entry-point. So a 'import ./index.html'; on the top of your app.tsx file will probably trigger the file-loader

Comment: Oh, that's a nice piece of information @thsorens. How can I do that in Typescript, so the ts-compiler agrees with it?

Comment: I havent really tried typescript with webpack before, only tried most other js/css/sass and so on. But i would think that since this import i used as an example doesnt try to import it into any variable, then why would typescript complain about it lacking any types? I would think that import Test from './index.html' would blow up in TS, but import './index.html'; should be fine?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2709

There you can see in the first comment that it should work;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

```
{
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do I need to use another package? Is `file-loader`not explicitly made for this?

Comment: @Robin I have edited. Loader was optional. It did nothing because html file isn't imported in entry. it's path in template